# Vim mapping ctrl-k

Tags: vim, mapping

I use <kbd>K</kbd> to move cursor line down in a file.

but I want to add a mapping so that when I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>K</kbd> the cursor moves to move 7 lines down in a file.

I have put this in my .vimrc file:

```
nmap <c-k> 7k
```

but what that does is move 7 lines down and then it enters a spacebar.

How do I stop it from entering the spacebar?

Comment: You may want to add `set list listchars=trail:-` to your `.vimrc` in order to be able to see trailing whitespaces.

Comment: I've already noticed another error in the .vimrc due to this line, so it's really worth having.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have a space following the `7k` in your nmap.

`:nmap <C-k> 7k` works correctly for me, but if I put a space after the `7k` then I reproduce the behavior you've described.